# How to max height on floating grid items

Tags: css

I often have a situation where there's a series of items floating left with a percentage width. I want all these items to have a set height of whatever the longest item is so they all stack and evenly.

http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/bnfmD

```
.box {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  float: left;
}
```

You'll notice the second to last `.box` is making the last one sit in the wrong place.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another div around every third box with auto height.

Comment: This doesn't really work since the amount of columns displayed horizontally changes on different breakpoints. Any other ideas? :)